# Convert data to be used as Apexcharts category

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, apexcharts

**first of all sorry about my english...**
I am trying to present a diagram in my App which represents the clients with status active and inactive.

the data I got back from the database looks like this..

```
"clientsOverview": [
        {
            "date": "Mar 2022",
            "count": 1,
            "clientStatus": "inactive"
        },
        {
            "date": "Mar 2022",
            "count": 1,
            "clientStatus": "active"
        },
        {
            "date": "Apr 2022",
            "count": 2,
            "clientStatus": "active"
        },
        {
            "date": "May 2022",
            "count": 1,
            "clientStatus": "inactive"
        },
        {
            "date": "Jun 2022",
            "count": 1,
            "clientStatus": "inactive"
        },
        {
            "date": "Jun 2022",
            "count": 1,
            "clientStatus": "active"
        }
    ],
```

I have manipulated this data in frontend using reduce mehtode

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const category = [] ;
    let data =[]
    clientsOverview?.map(item => {
      category.push(item.date)
    })
    data = Object.values(clientsOverview.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
      acc[curr.clientStatus] = acc[curr.clientStatus] || { name: curr.clientStatus, data: [] };
      acc[curr.clientStatus].data.push(curr.count);
      return acc;
  }, {}))
    setData(data)
    setCategory(category)
  }, [])
```

so my data now has this format...

```
"clientsOverview": [
        {
            "title": "active",
            "data": [
                1,
                2,
                1
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "inactive",
            "data": [
                1,
                1,
                1
            ]
        }
    ],
```

and the array category has this format

```
["Mar 2022", "Mar 2022", "Apr 2022", "May 2022", "Jun 2022", "Jun 2022"]
```

and when I try to display this data as a chart, I end up with these results
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgAU9.png)

```html
<div style={{ width: "100%"}} className="pt-3">
      <ReactApexChart  
      options = {{
        chart: {
          width: 380,
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: category
        },
        responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 480,
          options: {
            chart: {
              width: 200
            },
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom'
            }
          }
        }]
      } } 
      series= {data} type = "area" height={450} width={380}  />
    </div>
```

the question now if there is any way I can display my data correctly, like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5UoF.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data correctly, assuming the y starts at 1 for the lowest value. displays the chart correctly, doesn't it? The first data array has the values of `[1,2,1]`, resulting in an arch while the second has the values of `[1,1,1]`, resulting in a flat line. But I assume you want the y-axis to start at 0? To do that you need to add the following:

```
 yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            tickAmount: 2
          },
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/apexchartschart-egkfsu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i think the data should be in this format... const data = [ { title: "active", data: [1, 2, 0, 1] }, { title: "inactive", data: [1, 1, 1, 0] } ]; because for example for May I have no active clients and the same in Jun the inactive clients are 0 https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-firefly-z0vrqu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your clientsOverview data currently doesn't know that every data point is connected to a month, so you need to make so every point has a month tied to it.